# AWS Lambda - Return JSON Array

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using a python lambda to connect and query our data warehouse. I need the results to be returned like this:

```
[
    {
        "py/object": "app.Object",
        "TS": "2021-07-22 19:25:53.410000"
    }
]
```

However, I'm getting this instead:

```
"[{\"py/object\": \"app.Object\", \"TS\": \"2021-07-23 06:05:13.993000\"}]"
```

What do I need to do to get the output format desired?

Comment: Are you going to the lambda via API Gateway?

Comment: They're equivalent as far as I can see. One is JSON, while the other is serialized, stringified JSON (that your client would have to parse from the JSON string, e.g. using JSON.parse in JavaScript or json.loads in Python).

Comment: I wasn't in this case. I was invoking directly from test console.

Comment: Weird thing is, deploying via Chalice was able to get me the desired format. But I want to learn to replicate that result WITHOUT relying on Chalice